# Oracle_How to insert data from slow select query into two tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have searched but can't get answer for this (maybe wrong keyword...)

I come to this problem today when I need to create a procedure to calculate data to save to 2 report table in 2 different schemas. Let say those two tables have same structure.

The query to calculate data may take more than 60 seconds (data may or may not change the result of SELECT statemant if run again)

I have two way to insert data to those two table:

> 1. Just run insert TWO time with that same select query.
> 2. Using a GTT - global temporary table  to save calculated data from SELECT query, then INSERT to those two tables using data in that GTT.

I wonder if Oracle will keep cache of result for the SELECT query so that the first way will have better performance then second way (but have longer code, and duplicate code, not synchronized?).

So could anyone confirm and explain the right way to solve this for me? Or a better way of doing this?

Thank you,

Appendix 1:

```
INSERT INTO report_table (col1, col2, ....)
SELECT .....
FROM ..... 
--(long query)
;
INSERT INTO center_schema.report_table (col1, col2, ....)
SELECT .....
FROM ..... 
--same select query as above
;
```

And 2:

```
INSERT INTO temp_report_table(col1, col2, ...)
SELECT .....
FROM ..... 
--(long query)
;
INSERT INTO report_table (col1, col2, ....)
SELECT col1, col2, ....
FROM temp_report_table
;
INSERT INTO center_schema.report_table (col1, col2, ....)
SELECT col1, col2, ....
FROM temp_report_table
;
```

Comment: The GTT sounds like the way to go.  If you run the select statement twice as part of the same transaction, it should actually produce the same results, even if the data within the query changes.  If you commit between queries, then it can change.  If you don't care, the GTT will trade memory (temporarily) for the cost of re-running the query -- for a 60-second query, that's a good trade

Comment: Please beware, the sentence "_If you run the select statement twice as part of the same transaction, it should actually produce the same results_" is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have a third option - the wonderful multi-insert...

```
INSERT ALL
    INTO report_table (col1, col2, ....)
        VALUES (X.col1, X.col2, ...)
    INTO center_schema.report_table (col1, col2, ...)
        VALUES (X.col1, X.col2, ...)
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM your_table X
--(long query)
;
```

For a detailed info on this nice way of loading multiple tables at once please refer to the respective part of [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55088).

Comment: Thank you for this multi insert solution!